# LLVM IR generated code to native code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm-ir

I am learning how compilers work. For the learning I used several books and tutorials and at some point stumbled upon this issue that I cannot resolve.

The complete tutorial code I followed can be found at [Github repository](https://github.com/akamensky/bold)

This code produces IR code and successfully executes it. However if I try to save the code as `example.ll` file and (using `llc`) compile to native assembly, then this assembly fails to be compiled into native executable (using nasm and ld). I also tried to compile IR into native object files and then compile it using g++ (same as parser compiled in the make file of tutorial), which also fails. I would like to find a way to actually compile my generated IR code into executable binary file (at least for elf64).

The generated IR code [example.ll]:

```
; ModuleID = 'main'

@.str = private constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define internal void @echo(i64 %toPrint) {
entry:
  %0 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i64 %toPrint)
  ret void
}

define internal void @main() {
entry:
  %0 = call i64 @do_math(i64 11)
  call void @echo(i64 %0)
  %1 = call i64 @do_math(i64 12)
  call void @echo(i64 %1)
  call void @printi(i64 10)
  ret void
}

declare void @printi(i64)

define internal i64 @do_math(i64 %a1) {
entry:
  %a = alloca i64
  store i64 %a1, i64* %a
  %x = alloca i64
  %0 = load i64* %a
  %1 = mul i64 %0, 5
  store i64 %1, i64* %x
  %2 = load i64* %x
  %3 = add i64 %2, 3
  ret i64 %3
}
```

Then via asm:

```
$ llc-3.5 -filetype=asm -x86-asm-syntax=intel -o example.asm example.ll
$ nasm example.asm
example.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
example.asm:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
example.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected
example.asm:3: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
example.asm:3: error: parser: instruction expected
example.asm:4: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
example.asm:4: error: parser: instruction expected
example.asm:5: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0: # %entry:3: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0: # %entry:12: error: parser: instruction expected
...
...
<many similar errors here>
```

Or via GCC:

```
$ llc-3.5 -filetype=obj -o example.o example.ll
$ g++ native.o example.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

PS: Contribution to the repository to modify code accordingly (to make it work) would be more than welcome!

**UPD**: as requested

**asm code**:

```
    .text
    .file   "example.ll"
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   echo,@function
echo:                                   # @echo
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    pushq   %rax
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rdi, %rcx
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    callq   printf
    popq    %rax
    retq
.Ltmp1:
    .size   echo, .Ltmp1-echo
    .cfi_endproc

    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    pushq   %rax
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $11, %edi
    callq   do_math
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   echo
    movl    $12, %edi
    callq   do_math
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   echo
    movl    $10, %edi
    callq   printi
    popq    %rax
    retq
.Ltmp3:
    .size   main, .Ltmp3-main
    .cfi_endproc

    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   do_math,@function
do_math:                                # @do_math
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rsp)
    leaq    (%rdi,%rdi,4), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rsp)
    leaq    3(%rdi,%rdi,4), %rax
    retq
.Ltmp4:
    .size   do_math, .Ltmp4-do_math
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
.L.str:
    .asciz  "%d\n"
    .size   .L.str, 4


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

**Output of nm**:

```
$ nm example.o 
0000000000000060 t do_math
0000000000000000 t echo
0000000000000020 t main
                 U printf
                 U printi
```

Comment: Could you post the assembly code that llc generated?

Comment: Also, what do you get from `nm example.o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The assembly file**

The reason you can't assemble `example.asm` is probably that it is in AT&T syntax, whereas `nasm` expects Intel syntax. It appears that you've asked `llc` to output Intel syntax, but you got the flag wrong. According to [this manual](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html), it's `--x86-asm-syntax` (notice the double dash).

I suspect that you may be better off assembling with `as` (the GNU assembler) instead, as there are many mutually incompatible dialects of Intel syntax; I'm not really sure which one LLVM speaks. To do this, use the command:

```
$ as example.asm -o example.o
```

**The object file**

The reason you cannot link your object file with the C library is that you've declared your `main` function to have [internal linkage](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#linkage-types) (that's the `define internal`). Like the `static` keyword in C, it makes the symbol "invisible" outside of the object file, as evidenced by the lowercase 't' in the `nm` output.

When creating the LLVM function object for `main`, you should set its linkage type to `llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage`.

The same problem appears in the assembly file, of course - it's the absence of a `.global main`.

---

Don't take this to mean that you should give *all* functions external linkage; if a function is only used in the translation unit where it's defined, it really should have internal linkage. You just can't do it for `main`.

Comment: 1 - Thanks, using `as` has helped to build object file from asm file, but I guess this is exactly what happens if i first use `llc` to get object file and then I still should apply linker.
2 - How would I fix this issue with `main` being declared as `define internal`? This code is generated by output of LLVM based parser (you can check repository for the entire code) and documentation of LLVM is so vague that I have no idea how to do it! As a side note - if I manually edit `example.ll` to remove `internal` from declaration - `g++` compilation works as a charm and I get executable file!

Comment: Never mind! Simple digging a little more in the code tells me to use `llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage`! This fixes my issue! Please add this information to your answer for anyone else looking into similar problem.